# Flutter iOS Launch Image for development environment

Tags: ios, flutter, splash-screen

I'm using [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) link for adding the launcher image on iOS, however, there's no guidance for changing the launcher image depending on the scheme. For the app icon I'm using the **Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name** depending on the scheme I set up the corresponding image (see attached image below).

[image]

Comment: Is same as with the app icon and it is called "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name". Also you have to add in the assets a LaunchImage set for each scheme